# MERGE clause with undirected relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have a question about MERGE clause.

According to the manual([link](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-on-an-undirected-relationship)), "MERGE can also be used with an undirected relationship. When it needs to create a new one, it will pick a direction.".

Query

```
MATCH (charlie:Person { name: 'Charlie Sheen' }),(oliver:Person { name: 'Oliver Stone' })
MERGE (charlie)-[r:KNOWS]-(oliver)
RETURN r
```

Result

```
+-------------+
| r           |
+-------------+
| :KNOWS[8]{} |
+-------------+
1 row
Relationships created: 1
```

Q1) How is the direction determined?

Q2) Why do not create two relationships(incoming and outgoing)?

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking two separate questions here. Although your questions share a common theme, the norm on StackOverflow is to create a unique question post for each question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

As it's not listed in the manual, I'm not sure that it matters. You should only be merging an undirected relationship if it doesn't matter to you or your data model, and likewise for queries with undirected relationships. If it matters, then use a directed relationship.

Neo4j can traverse a single relationship backwards or forward without penalty. Usually there's no reason to have two relationships. There are some cases though where it makes sense, such as when a relationships in one direction does not imply the relationship is reciprocated. For example, a :FOLLOWING relationship in a social network. One person can follow another, but that does not mean the other person is following back, that would require a second relationship going the other direction.